# Set image as object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set an image as object in ReactJS but i don't know the syntax , i looked on google but i didn't find anything! I don't know if it's even possible ?

Here's the code:

```
const items = [
  {
    src: '../images/hb1.jpg',
    altText: 'slide 1',
    caption: 'dfjkdfjksdfjk',
    header:'something'
  },
  {
    src: '../images/hb1.jpg',
    altText: 'slide 1',
    caption: ' asdasdasd',
    header:'something'

  },
  {
    src:'../images/hb1.jpg',
    altText: 'Slide 3',
    caption: 'dasjdasdkj',
    header:'something'

  }
];
```

i call it later on here:

```
<img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
```

I tried 'url('../url')' but didn't work!

Comment: Assuming "image goes here" was a URL (relative is fine), that's how you'd do it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). You can use http://placeholder.com for the images.

Comment: I Updated to post ! and i also tried 'url('my image path')' , isn't it supposed to be working that way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image path should be relative to the project root images directory of the site.

For example:

Your domain is www.example.com. Your images are placed in your public folder `/images`.

Therefore in your app, you should link the image as follows:

```
<img src='/images/test.png' />
```